# Align space between text and input form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have the following input form created dynamically. I can not change the form components. SO, how do I style it so that, it creates dynamic style and aligns space between text label and the input box?

```html
   <form> <label>name <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData['name']" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse"></label>
<label>name <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData['name']" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse"></label>
<label>name <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData['name']" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse"></label></form>
```

Comment: did you use bootstrap ?

Comment: yes, i did use bootstrap. but this one is auto generated by - https://github.com/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms

Comment: can you make a plunkr or past a screenshot to see how it render in your code ? i think you can override CSS property but in the directive demo the input are well aligned so maybe yo missing something

Answer (score 0):

Use css styling.
eg:

```css
<style>
 input[type="text"] {
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>
```